# i need assistance with looping lists together

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
A[15, 12, 13, 19, 14, 10, 16, 20, 9, 18, 8, 7]

B[19, 14, 8, 16, 20, 9, 18, 15, 12, 13, 7, 10]
```

all the elements are similar, I just need help coming up with a brute force algorithm that would print the indexes of similar elements into a list

for example:

```
A[0] with B[7] (for number 15)

A[1] with B[8] (for number 12)
```

that would be the output

and so forth...

i have started with

```
a = [15, 12, 13, 19, 14, 10, 16, 20, 9, 18, 8, 7]
b = [19, 14, 8, 16, 20, 9, 18, 15, 12, 13, 7, 10]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b)):
```

and i have no idea where to go from here, well, i have tried printing index, but it just says

```
ValueError: 0 is not in list
```

and tried another way but it just printed the entire list like 10 times or so...

Comment: You just need to look up the index of i in b, theres no need for the second loop

Comment: @Sayse That's only true if the real data contains no dulicate values (since `index()` always finds the first match).

Answer (score 4):

assuming all elements of the list `a` are unique and occur exactly once in list `b` you could use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#common-sequence-operations) in this way:

```
a = [15, 12, 13, 19, 14, 10, 16, 20, 9, 18, 8, 7]
b = [19, 14, 8, 16, 20, 9, 18, 15, 12, 13, 7, 10]

for ia, x in enumerate(a):
    ib = b.index(x)
    print(f"a[{ia}] with b[{ib}] (for number {x})")
```

it outputs

```
a[0] with b[7] (for 15)
a[1] with b[8] (for 12)
a[2] with b[9] (for 13)
a[3] with b[0] (for 19)
...
```

---

for long `list`s it may be worthwhile speeding up the `b.index()` lookup by creating a dictionary first:

```
idx_b = {x: idx for idx, x in enumerate(b)}

for ia, x in enumerate(a):
    ib = idx_b[x]
    print(f"a[{ia}] with b[{ib}] (for number {x})")
```

Comment: Im not sure if the process of creating a dictionary would make this much more efficient, seems like the best approach to me

Comment: @Sayse yeah. you are probably right... it just bothered me that this scales with `n^2` while it could be done in `2*n` .

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficien method, but since you said brute-force, this should work:

```
A = [15, 12, 13, 19, 14, 10, 16, 20, 9, 18, 8, 7]

B = [19, 14, 8, 16, 20, 9, 18, 15, 12, 13, 7, 10]

for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if a == b:
            print('A['+ str(A.index(a)) + '] and B[' + str(B.index(b)) + '] for number ' + str(a))
```

Output:

```
A[0] and B[7] for number 15
A[1] and B[8] for number 12
A[2] and B[9] for number 13
A[3] and B[0] for number 19
A[4] and B[1] for number 14
A[5] and B[11] for number 10
A[6] and B[3] for number 16
A[7] and B[4] for number 20
A[8] and B[5] for number 9
A[9] and B[6] for number 18
A[10] and B[2] for number 8
A[11] and B[10] for number 7
```

Answer (score -1):

this work for me.

```
a = [15, 12, 13, 19, 14, 10, 16, 20, 9, 18, 8, 7]
b = [19, 14, 8, 16, 20, 9, 18, 15, 12, 13, 7, 10]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if a[i]==b[j]:
            print(f"a[{i}] with b[{j}] (for number {a[i]})")
```